# RxJs-5-to-6-migrate crashes

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to update my project from Angular 4 to Angular 6.
I followed the update steps found on the Angular website and all goes quite smoothly.
However, when trying to use the rxjs-5-to-6-migrate script, it crashes.

I've tried various variations of paths, but noothing seems to work.

I've no idea what's going on...

```
PS D:\workspace\project> rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
Running the automatic migrations. Please, be patient and wait until the execution completes.
child_process.js:615
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: "d:\Applications\node-v9.11.1-win-x64\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\node_modules\.bin\tslint" -c "d:\Applications\node-v9.11.1-win-x64\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.json" -p "src/tsconfig.app.json" --fix
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:575:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:612:13)
    at migrate (d:\Applications\node-v9.11.1-win-x64\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:18:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Applications\node-v9.11.1-win-x64\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:25:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a outdated dependency (probably tslint) what caused this. After updating all dependencies in the package.json, it worked.

Comment: I have the same issue. I do a clean install and have the same error on Windows 7, node v9.9.0, npm 5.10.0. Some ideas?

Comment: Well, I found that I have an global outdated version of `run-js` that holded an old version of `typescript`. I just uninstalled it and now it run seemly.