# usng rxjs-5-to-6-migrate correctly. issues with tsconfig path

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, tsconfig, rxjs6

The documentation to use rxjs-5-to-6-migrate states the following:

```
To refactor TypeScript code so that it doesn't depend on rxjs-compat, you can use rxjs-tslint.

npm i -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p [path/to/tsconfig.json]
```

So I did that and then copied the

root path to my tsconfig file

```
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p [/home/ri
ckus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/frontendsuitsandtables/suitsandtables/tsconfig.json]
```

But when I run the command I get the following **error**.

```
Running the automatic migrations. Please, be patient and wait until the execution completes.
child_process.js:643
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/node_modules/.bin/tslint" -c "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.json" -p "[home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/frontendsuitsandtables/suitsandtables/tsconfig.json" --fix
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:603:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:640:13)
    at migrate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:18:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rxjs-tslint/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:25:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
```

But for why? It seems this  code is more fickle than my ex and unfortunately I can't run away from this.

I checked this answer and it did not help: 
[RxJs-5-to-6-migrate crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639923/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate-crashes)

Comment: same issue. Wish I had a fix for it.

Comment: I fixed installing typescript global with latest `npm i -g typescript@latest`

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the square brackets around the path to `tsconfig.json`.

```
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/frontendsuitsandtables/suitsandtables/tsconfig.json
```

You can also start the command inside the source root of your project (first step optional, if you are already in the folder).

```
cd /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/frontendsuitsandtables/suitsandtables/

rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p tsconfig.json
```